# Can't import .csv file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I'm trying to insert data for 46 mountains that have columns with different data types. I have integer columns for id and elevation then a couple varchar columns for name and description as well as some decimal columns for trail distance and avg hiking time. I have created an excel spreadsheet with all the data and try to import it into MySQL with the following:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE
'mountainData.csv'
INTO TABLE mountains
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

I have placed the data file in the folder where the saved sql file is so I don't have to specify the entire path. MySQL does find the file and tries to execute the command but I have run into two errors that make the command fail.

If I save the file from excel as CSV UTF-8(Comma delimited)(*.csv) it seems that MySQL interprets the integer value as a string and I get:

```
Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '﻿1' for column 'id' at row 1
```

then if I save the file from excel as CSV (Comma delimited)(*.csv) I get:

```
Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"With an elevation of 5,344 feet above 
sea level, Mount Marcy is'
```

That is the last column which is the description so it seems when saved in this format it accepts the first seven columns and moves through them fine and errors out on the description.

This is how the table I am trying to insert the data into is formatted:

```
create table mountains (
    id integer primary key,
    name varchar(64),
    elevation integer,
    difficulty integer,
    ascent integer,
    length decimal(3,1),
    hikeTime decimal(3,1),
    description varchar(2000)
);
```

The description is fairly long and does have its own paragraphs if that makes a difference. I have tried to execute the command with and without the enclosed by statement but that ended up not having any effect. If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it!

I am running Windows 10, saving the csv directly from Excel and running the SQL command through MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Comment: I use [heidi sql](https://www.heidisql.com/) for importing csv

Comment: Yea I saw there were some third party options to achieve it but was hoping to avoid them. I'll take a look at heidi sql if there are no other suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Show us the whole line that is causing trouble.